# Aggregate over the column that is not in group by list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For example I have the following table:

```
declare @table table(val int, dt datetime)
insert into @table values
(10, '2018-3-20 16:00'),
(12, '2018-3-20 14:00'),
(14, '2018-3-20 12:00'),
(16, '2018-3-20 10:00'),
(10, '2018-3-19 14:00'),
(12, '2018-3-19 12:00'),
(14, '2018-3-19 10:00'),
(10, '2018-3-18 12:00'),
(12, '2018-3-18 10:00')
```

I try to aggregate using the column in group by, it is okay:

```
select day, MAX(val) as max_by_value from
(
select DATEPART(DAY, dt) as day, val from @table
) q
group by day
```

It returns:

```
day max_by_value
18  12
19  14
20  16
```

Now I need max value by time of the day, so I need 10 as result for each day.
I try to use `over` but it say `Column '@table.dt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

```
select DATEPART(DAY, dt), MAX(val) as max_by_value
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by DATEPART(DAY, dt) order by dt desc) as max_by_date
from @table
group by DATEPART(DAY, dt)
```

I understand why I get this error but don't understand how to fix my issue. Could you please help to find some way to fill `[max_by_date]` column?

As result I expect the following output:

```
day max_by_value max_by_time
18  12           10
19  14           10
20  16           10
```

Comment: "Now I need max value by time of the day". Unless I'm missing something, simply group by `dt`...

Comment: I need 3 columns at the same time - `[day], [max_by_value], [max_by_time]`

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Please edit your question to include desired results.

Comment: Done, it was described in the text "so I need 10 as result for each day"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from 2012 version, you can use the [`First_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql) window function:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT DATEPART(DAY, dt), 
        MAX(val) OVER (partition by DATEPART(DAY, dt)) as max_by_value,
        FIRST_VALUE(val) OVER (partition by DATEPART(DAY, dt) order by dt desc) as max_by_date
FROM @table
```

Note: I've used the `OVER` clause for the `MAX` function instead of using `group by`.

With 2008 version, you can use a subquery instead:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT DATEPART(DAY, dt), 
        MAX(val) OVER (partition by DATEPART(DAY, dt)) as max_by_value,
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 val
            FROM @table as t1
            WHERE DATEPART(DAY, t1.dt) = DATEPART(DAY, t0.dt)
            ORDER BY dt DESC
        ) as max_by_date
FROM @table as t0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just worry about performance. Since there are a lot of calculated records that will be removed by `distinct` it looks like this fact can affect performance. What do you think?

Comment: `Distinct` might slow queries down, for sure. You need to test on actual data with relevant volume to see if that's too slow. If it is, check the execution plan.

Comment: Yep, I will check. Anyways do you have any idea how to change your query to improve performance? I have too big table and I believe I need more effective way if possible.